# Query for entries with the same title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

I'm coding the site http://Meer.li, a site where users can upload designs.

In my design model, I need to find designs that have the same title and group them. How do I make such a query?

Right now I just have:

```
@designs = Design.order_by( :created_at, :desc )
```

I'm running rails 3.2, ruby 1.9.3 and I'm using mongoid for the database.

**Further Explanation:**

Sorry if I weren't specific enough. I have a lot of designs and some of these designs have the same title. First of all I want to find all the designs that have the same title. Second of all I want to group those designs within an array, so I don't need several arrays to get my designs. Last thing, is that the designs with the same title, should only be grouped if they're made by the same user

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough. I've edited my question above. Tell me if there's anything else you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i got your question right this should do the trick:

```
@designs = Design.where(:title => "someTitle").order_by( :created_at, :desc )
```

**UPDATE:**

so maybe this works

```
Design.select("title, count(title) as title_count").group(:title).having("title_count > 1")
```

never tried this with mongo db - maybe it works or it helps you to adapt it for your needs

hope this helps!

Comment: It isn't exactly what I'm looking for. This would give me all the designs with the title "someTitle". I want all the designs that share the same title... not a specific title. Do you have a suggestion for that?

Comment: so you want all designs with a title which exists more than once?

Comment: That's exactly what I want :-).

Comment: That looks close, but it gives me the error: private method `select' called for Design:Class. What can that be about?

Comment: might be related to mongo db - select may not be available with mongo db - but I am not really familiar with it - I guess you are using mongoid? they have a nice documentation about querying http://mongoid.org/docs/querying.html